# CNN model predicts only 1 class and gives sigmoid prediction always 0.99-1

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am beginner in CV and try to make an object detector based on the article.

I got folders with frames of size about 900 * 1200. I load frames and make positive and negative samples of size 64 * 64 from them. The process of making samples the next: positive samples are cropped images with object, negative samples are made based on ROI which I found with blob detector. For this purpose I write custom data generator. As I made it first time I can made mistake there. (Code will be a little below)

Data generator yields X and Y, where one y for positive sample is a vector like [1 (class), x1, y1, x2, y2] and for negative is a vector like [0 (class),0, 0, 0, 0]. When I train model, loss is decreasing from 2000 on 1-st epoch to 3-4 on 20-th epoch. But model predicts always 0.99-1. for any image (positive or negative) on the same train generator.

I know that it happens sometimes because of imbalanced data. But I plot images, and they were balanced. I try to make images imbalanced with higher amount of class 0 , but model again predicts all images 0.99-1. Also I try another arhitecture of model, different learning rates, amount of epoches, but always the same. Of course, when I drop making positive samples from generator, I got predictions 0 for every negative sample.

Also I try to drop coordinates from y and predict only class, loss was 0, but model again predicts the same, moreover, pictures which were in train generator will be the same in test generator.

I am beginner, so I am sorry for quality of code.

**Generator code**

```
dt = np.dtype(np.float32)

def generator(batches=128):
    while True:
        for j in range(batches):
            Xs = []
            Ys = []
            count = 0
            
            while count < 16:
             
                day_or_night = random.randint(0,1)

                if day_or_night == 0: 
                    folder_day = random.randint(1,13)
                    path_0 = '/Users/Name/Downloads/archive/Annotations/Annotations/dayTrain/dayClip{}/frameAnnotationsBOX.csv'.format(folder_day)
                    csv_file = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=path_0, sep=';')

                else:
                    folder_night = random.randint(1,5)
                    path_0 = '/Users/Name/Downloads/archive/Annotations/Annotations/nightTrain/nightClip{}/frameAnnotationsBOX.csv'.format(folder_night)
                    csv_file = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=path_0, sep=';')

                # choose picture 
                i = random.randint(0, len(csv_file.iloc[:,0].unique())-1)# choose random number of picture in folder
                full_pic_name = csv_file.iloc[:,0].unique()[i] # with index above choose full name picture 
                pic_name = csv_file.iloc[:,0].unique()[i].split('/')[1] # with index above choose picture 

                if day_or_night == 0:
                    path_to_img = '/Users/Name/Downloads/archive/dayTrain/dayTrain/dayClip{}/frames/'.format(folder_day) + pic_name
                else:
                    path_to_img = '/Users/Name/Downloads/archive/nightTrain/nightTrain/nightClip{}/frames/'.format(folder_night) + pic_name

                img = cv.imread(path_to_img)
                img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                # find coordinates
                number_of_same_pic = len(csv_file[csv_file.iloc[:,0] == full_pic_name].iloc[:,0]) # how many pic with same name
                img = cv.copyMakeBorder(img, 100, 100, 100, 100, cv.BORDER_REPLICATE) 

                # blobbing
                params = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
                params.minThreshold = 1
                params.maxThreshold = 255
                params.filterByArea = True
                params.minArea = 100 
                #params.maxArea = 1500
                params.filterByCircularity = False
                params.filterByConvexity = False
                params.filterByInertia = False

                detector = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
                keypoints = detector.detect(img)

                kps = np.array([key for key in keypoints])

                for i in range(number_of_same_pic):
                    if count < 16:
                        # coors of box
                        x1 = csv_file[csv_file.iloc[:,0] == full_pic_name].iloc[i,2]+100
                        y1 = csv_file[csv_file.iloc[:,0] == full_pic_name].iloc[i,3]+100
                        x2 = csv_file[csv_file.iloc[:,0] == full_pic_name].iloc[i,4]+100
                        y2 = csv_file[csv_file.iloc[:,0] == full_pic_name].iloc[i,5]+100
                        
                        # condition for keypoins which are not boxes - TAKES MUCH TIME
                        for key in keypoints:
                            keypoints = [key for key in keypoints if not ((x1 < key.pt[0] < x2) and (y1 < key.pt[1] < y2))]     

                        # crop image a little bigger than box 
                        cropped_img = img[y1-10:y2+10, x1-10:x2+10]
                        
                        new_x1 = 10
                        new_y1 = 10
                        new_x2 = 10 + (x2-x1)
                        new_y2 = 10 + (y2-y1)

                        w = cropped_img.shape[1]
                        h = cropped_img.shape[0]
                        
                        #coefficients of scaling
                        Rx = (64 / w) 
                        Ry = (64 / h)
                        
                        x1 = ceil(10*Rx)
                        y1 = ceil(10*Ry) 
                        x2 = ceil(new_x2*Rx)
                        y2 = ceil(new_y2*Ry)

                        cropped_img = cv.resize(cropped_img, (64, 64))
                        cropped_img = cropped_img.reshape(1, 64, 64, 3)

                        box = np.array([1, x1, y1, x2, y2], dtype=dt)

                        Xs.append(np.array(cropped_img, dtype=dt) / 255.), Ys.append(box)

                        count += 1

                for k in range(len(keypoints)):
                    if count < 16:
                        k_x1 = int(round(keypoints[k].pt[0]-32))
                        k_y1 = int(round(keypoints[k].pt[1]-32))
                        k_x2 = int(round(keypoints[k].pt[0]+32))
                        k_y2 = int(round(keypoints[k].pt[1]+32))

                        cropped_img = img[k_y1:k_y2, k_x1:k_x2]
                        cropped_img = cv.resize(cropped_img, (64, 64))
                        cropped_img = cropped_img.reshape(1, 64, 64, 3)

                        box = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=dt)

                        Xs.append(np.array(cropped_img, dtype=dt) / 255.), Ys.append(box)

                        count += 1
                        
            yield Xs, Ys
```

**Loss code**

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, [1, 5])
    y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, [1, 5])
    
    class_loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true[:, 0], y_pred[:, 0])
    reg_loss = mse(y_true[:, 1:5], y_pred[:, 1:5])
    
    return class_loss + 2 * reg_loss * y_true[:, 0]
```

**Model code**

```
IMG_HEIGHT = 64
IMG_WIDTH = 64
IMG_CHANNELS = 3

def make_model():
    input_layer = Input(shape=[IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS])

    layer_1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)

    layer_2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(layer_1)
    layer_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer_2)

    
    layer_3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(layer_2)
    layer_3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(layer_3)
    
    layer_4 = Flatten()(layer_3)
    layer_4 = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(layer_4)
    
    layer_5 = Dense(200, activation='relu')(layer_4)
    
    out_1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layer_5)
    out_2 = Dense(4, activation='linear')(layer_5)
    
    x = Concatenate()([out_1, out_2])
    
    model = Model(input_layer, x)
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss = custom_loss)
    
    return model
```

Comment: Your generator is probably the one to blame. It seems that you are filling your data with positive sample, and never with negative sample (depending on the value of `number_of_same_pic` which I can't guess).

Comment: In annotation picture has coordinates of object. So, if there are many object on picture, some pictures will be with the same name in folder. So I iterate for this number to get coordinates of every object on picture and then get positive sample. Then I find coordinates of blob in keypoints list which is inside of object box and take away from list of blob keypoints. So I have list of keypoints which I can use for negative samples. I believe in problem in generator, but when I plot it, it seems good. But thank you for comment!